# Add gesture listener to child view without hiding parent's touch event

Tags: android, android-view, android-event, android-gesture

I want to have an overlay view to receive gesture events but still keep receiving onTouch event of parent(below) view. However, The gesture in child view seems *hide* parent onTouch event.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ParentView

            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ChildView android:background="#FF4433"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="200dp" android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

        </ChildView>

    </ParentView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Parent View:

```
public class ParentView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public ParentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Logger.write("Parent is touching");
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Client View:

```
public class ChildView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private GestureDetector myGestureDetector;
    private boolean isTapping;

    public ChildView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        myGestureDetector=new  GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector());
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        return  myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;    
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
                final int swipeMinDistance = vc.getScaledPagingTouchSlop();
                final int swipeMaxOffPath = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
                final int swipeThresholdVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() / 2;
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > swipeMaxOffPath) {
                    return false;
                }

                // right to left swipe
                if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > swipeMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) >
                        swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                    Logger.write("Swipe!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement GestureDetector in parent not in child view, otherwise you would need n detectors if parent has n child views.

Comment: referencing your answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070129/detecting-common-gestures-on-multiple-views-in-android)